# O-rings: Why a torus?

Tags: seals

O-rings are very common components in all kinds a machinery used to, say, keep a fluid from leaking from one side of a piston to another inside a cylinder. But why exactly are O-rings tori? Why are they not designed so that the contact side of the ring to the cylinder wall is flat? Wouldn't this give a more secure seal?

Comment: Think about what happens to the shape when under pressure.

Comment: There are seals for some shafts that are rectangular in section : designed to go into grooves and fitting them can be a challenge ... One agricultural tractor (Case International 6cyl turbo) had two of those seals on the pto shaft : needed to use a thin shim to get past the first groove to the second without slicing it...

Comment: @joojaa I can't really say.. It compresses?